# How to get the SharePoint Web Applications Portal Super User Account and Portal Super Reader Account?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, administration, web-application

I was trying to resolve "cache is not configured" issue on SP2010 production box and came across the solution being discussed in one of the [SharePoint chick blog](http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2010/10/06/resolving-the-super-user-account-utilized-by-the-cache-is.aspx)

The problem is before I try out the fix I would like to first **verify** whether the **Portal Super User Account** and **Portal Super Reader Account** already exits, using Power Shell command-lets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technet documentation concerning configuring the object cache user accounts: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758656.aspx

Using the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell you can verify if the Super User and Super Reader accounts are already configured.

Firstly run the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell with Administrator rights.
Secondly type in the following commands:

```
Get-SPWebApplication
```

The command *Get-SPWebApplication* shows you the webapplications you have (excluding the Central Admin Webapplication)

Secondly choose the webapplication you would like to verify the superuser account for and type the following commands replacing *"x"* with the correct information:

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity "<WebApplication>"
$wa.Properties["portalsuperuseraccount"]
```

The command *$wa.Properties["portalsuperuseraccount"]* will show you the Super User account that is configured for that webapplication.

Thirdly to verify the Super Reader account:

```
$wa.Properties["portalsuperreaderaccount"]
```

The command *$wa.Properties["portalsuperreaderaccount"]* will show you the Super Reader account configured for the webapplication.

Comment: $wa.Properties["portalsuperuseraccount"]
I tried it, no value came in response in the cmd prompt, does it mean its not set?

Comment: @aDeveloper - If no value returns, it means it is not set. Do you still get the Windows Events in your Event viewer regarding the Super User and Super Reader accounts?

Comment: I have not yet implemented the fix as mentioned the blog I referred. I guess you are right I m not getting any value for the property because it was not set. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @aDeveloper - You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following script as mentioned in https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/spjr/2018/02/07/sharepoint-the-complete-guide-to-portalsuperuseraccount-and-portalsuperreaderaccount/

## Output super user / reader for all web apps:

```
add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ea silentlycontinue

$was = Get-SPWebApplication

foreach ($wa in $was)

{Write-host "Web App: " $wa.url

Write-host "Super User: " $wa.Properties["portalsuperuseraccount"]

Write-host "Super Reader: " $wa.Properties["portalsuperreaderaccount"]

Write-host " "}
```